Restricted 3-body: one large mass and two smaller ones
A restricted 3-body problem is usually understood as two large bodies and one much smaller one that doesn't affect the motion of the other two.
I am curious about a 3-body problem with one large body, unaffected by the other two, and two smaller bodies of comparable size. Something like Sun + Earth + Moon.
What would be a good reference to start from?

Lunar motion is quite hard to calculate to high precision, mostly because the Moon's mass is so high relative to the Earth's. I have some info on https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/55112/16685
